# Importar una tabla Excel a phpmyadmin manteniendo formatos de texto

Tags: php, excel, phpmyadmin

Quiero importar una tabla Excel a phpmyadmin manteniendo formatos de cursiva y negrita. (He conseguido todo lo que necesito excepto mantener los formatos de texto).

Tengo lo siguiente:

1. A través de un formulario el cliente inserta el archivo Excel
2. Con phpExcel recorro los datos para la importación.
3. Muestro la tabla en pantalla.
4. Inserto los datos en la tabla de phpmyadmin.

He leido en varios foros que en phpExcel existen instrucciones del tipo "getRichTextElements()" pero después de muchas (muuuchas) pruebas no consigo hacerlo funcionar, por lo que algo debo estar haciendo mal.

Este es el código. ¿Podría alguien decirme qué debo añadir para implementar la importación de los estilos?

```html
require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
   
//extraer los datos del excel
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('xls/tabla.xls');
$objHoja=$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(true,true,true,true);  
   
//mostrar en pantalla la tabla importada
echo '
  <table border="1" width="100%">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th><center><strong>B</strong></center></th>
   <th><center><strong>C</strong></center></th>
   <th><center><strong>D</strong></center></th>
   <th><center><strong>E</strong></center></th>
  </tr>
      
  <tr>
   <th>DATO1</th>
   <th>DATO2</th>
   <th>DATO3</th>
   <th>DATO4</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
       
 <tbody>  ';
   
foreach ($objHoja as $iIndice=>$objCelda) {
echo '
     <tr>
      <td>'.$objCelda['B'].'</td>
   <td>'.$objCelda['C'].'</td>
   <td>'.$objCelda['D'].'</td>
   <td>'.$objCelda['E'].'</td>
     </tr>
 ';
//guardar los datos para insertarlos en la tabla del servidor  
$dato1=$objCelda['B'];
$dato2=$objCelda['C'];  
$dato3=$objCelda['D'];
$dato4=$objCelda['E']; 
    
$sql="INSERT INTO mitabla (dato1, dato2, dato3, dato4) VALUES ('$dato1', '$dato2', '$dato3, '$dato4')";
mysqli_query($conect,$sql);
   }
echo '</tbody>
   </table>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Solución: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12979394/phpexcel-cannot-reads-styles-from-xls

Allí lo aplican con el `getStyle()` del sheet que esté activo.

Comment: No es recomendable que coloques links externos en respuestas, lo ideal es colocar la solución aquí y explicarte lo más que puedas y dejar el link solo _"para mas información..."_ o bien dejar el link en un comentario a la pregunta pero para eso debes de tener mas reputación.

Comment: gracias por el feedback!